# parameters_content value could not be deserialized

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using an inline deployment for azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment and I'm passing a parameter that uses the name of another terraform resource.

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapi" {
  name                = "${lower(var.deploymentEnvironment)}-webapi"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.frontendResourceGroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.frontendResourceGroup.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.appSvcPlan.id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "webapi_virtual_directory" {
  name                = "webapi_virtual_directory"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.frontendResourceGroup.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  template_content       = <<TEMPLATE
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
        "webAppName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualApplications":{
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue":[
            {
            "virtualPath": "/",
            "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
            "preloadEnabled": false,
            "virtualDirectories": null
            }
        ]
        }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
      {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/web')]",
          "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
          "properties": {
              "virtualApplications": "[parameters('virtualApplications')]"
          },
          "dependsOn": []
      }
  ]
}
  TEMPLATE
  parameters_content  = jsonencode({webAppName = azurerm_app_service.webapi.name})
  depends_on          = [azurerm_app_service.webapi]
}
```

When I run the terraform apply command, I get the error:

> Error: validating Template Deployment "webapi_virtual_directory"
> (Resource Group "frontendapps-rg"): requesting validating:
> resources.DeploymentsClient#Validate: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidRequestContent"
> Message="The request content was invalid and could  not be
> deserialized: 'Error converting value "ci-webapi" to type
> 'Azure.ResourceManager.Deployments.Templates.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'.
> Path 'properties.parameters.webAppName', line 1, position 861.'."
>
> on main.tf line 134, in resource
> "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment"
> "webapi_virtual_directory":  134: resource
> "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment"
> "webapi_virtual_directory" {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `parameters_content` property, I added `defaultValue` to the `template_content` like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "webapi_virtual_directory" {
  name                = "webapi_virtual_directory"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.frontendResourceGroup.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  template_content    = <<TEMPLATE
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "webAppName": {
        "type": "String",
        "defaultValue": "${azurerm_app_service.webapi.name}"
    },
    "virtualApplications":{
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue":[
        {
        "virtualPath": "/",
        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
        "preloadEnabled": false,
        "virtualDirectories": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/web')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "properties": {
          "virtualApplications": "[parameters('virtualApplications')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
TEMPLATE
  depends_on          = [azurerm_app_service.webapi]
}
```

Now I don't get the error validating template deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is a workaround, here's what you need to do to make `parameters_content` work:

This:

```
parameters_content = jsonencode({webAppName = azurerm_app_service.webapi.name})
```

Should be:

```
parameters_content = jsonencode(
{
    webAppName = { value = azurerm_app_service.webapi.name }
})
```

Since the value of the property `webAppName` is a more complex type containing a property called `value`.